# Restrict File Type in MVC5 File Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to completely remove the All Files dropdown option when uploading a file through MVC 5 HTML

@TempData["fileType"] accepts (.xml,.txt,.xml) it works but I want to completely remove All Files

```
 <input type="file" name="file" accept="@TempData["fileType"]"  />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a function of the OS/browser and you have no control over it. Use a validation attribute so that you get client and server side validation - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199870/how-to-validate-file-type-of-httppostedfilebase-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc-4/40200034#40200034) for an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cannot remove `All Files`  and it has nothing to do with `MVC` because  `<input type="file" name="file" />` is an `html tag` but you can validate the upload file either by using `javascript` for client side validation or you can use `c#` for server side validation.

For javascript validation [File Type validation with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231058/file-type-validation-with-javascript) and for server side check [File Type Validation MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619372/upload-file-and-validate-file-extension-and-file-size-mvc-5) . Server side validation is always preferred because javascript can be disabled from browser.

Comment: Thanks @Usman for your help, I know about the validations my only concern was to completely remove it.